# Relantionships between tables with duplicates (Excel)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

I'm trying to join two datasets where both have (and need to have) duplicates.

Here is an example with dummy data of both tables:

```
t.componentsneeded
ORDER    PRODUCT   PENDINGSALES    components    component_stock    
 1        REF1         100           COMP1            50              
 1        REF1         100           COMP2            100            
 1        REF1         100           COMP3            50             
 2        REF1         200           COMP1            50              
 2        REF1         200           COMP2            100             
 2        REF1         200           COMP3            50
```

And I would like to join the first table with this other one:

```
t.pendingtoarrive
ORDER DATE    ARRIVAL DATE    PURCHASE_ORDER   COMPONENT     UNITS
01/11/2020    01/12/2020          1              COMP1        100
15/11/2020    15/12/2020          2              COMP1        100
01/12/2020    01/01/2021          3              COMP1        50
```

The first dataset is pivoted in a table like this:

```
FILTER ORDER: ALL                               (COLUMN I WOULD JOIN)
COMPONENT       NEEDED        STOCK     TO_BUY      TO_ARRIVE
COMP1            300           50         250           250
COMP2            300           100        200            -
COMP3            300           50         250            -
```

I tried to create a new table with no duplicated values (COMPONENT) to connect both tables with it. But then Pivot table sums the total units from `t.pendingtoarrive` without taking the filters from `t.componentsneeded` in count (the only filter to have in mind is "COMPONENT"). I'd like to do it like this so the final user could double click values from TO_ARRIVE and it would open the table with the data. If there is any other way to achieve the same thing...

Thank you. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't understand how you get the results you show in your pivot of table 1 for the `STOCK` column.  It seems to be 1/2 the amount determined by summing the `component_stock` column for the particular component.   Will it always be 1/2? Or is there some other way you are computing this?  (perhaps by number of orders?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it's the average. COMP1 has 50 stock and I don't want it to sum over the different orders or products. It will always be 50 in every row

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+
You do a `Nested Join` and extract the appropriate values

- Make sure your two data sets are set up as `Tables`

  - Record the table names
- Open the PQ editor by either

  - open a blank query or
  - select a cell in data set 1 and `Data => Get & Transform => from Table/Range`
- `Home/Advanced Editor` and paste the code below into the Editor

  - Change the table names in the appropriate lines to reflect your **actual** table names
  - Examine the Applied Steps window, and the code, to see how it's done.

**M Code**

```
let
    //Get data set 1
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="needed"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ORDER", Int64.Type}, {"PRODUCT", type text}, {"PENDINGSALES", Int64.Type}, {"components", type text}, {"component_stock", Int64.Type}}),

    //Group by component to generate "pivot"
    //Note that "needed" is a SUM, and "stock" is an AVERAGE
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"components"}, {
            {"NEEDED", each List.Sum([PENDINGSALES]), type nullable number}, 
            {"STOCK", each List.Average([component_stock]), type nullable number}
            }),

    // Generate the "to buy" column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "TO_BUY", each [NEEDED]-[STOCK]),

    //Get data set 2
    Ordered = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="pendingArrive"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Ordered,{{"ORDER DATE", type date}, {"ARRIVAL DATE", type date}}),

    //Join with set 1
    join = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom","components",#"Changed Type1","COMPONENT","Joined"),

    //extract total for each componennt
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(join, "TO_ARRIVE", each List.Sum(Table.Column([Joined],"UNITS"))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Joined"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but sadly I think I need it as Pivot since some fields are calculated with DAX. If I do it the way you say, will the user be able to double click into TO_ARRIVE column to open the dataset?